# URL Displaying Wrong Form and View in Django

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to render a form where the only field is a dropdown. I have the form, view, .html, url all set up.  But when I access this url, it shows a different form and view and I suppose also a different .html.  I am so confused on why this is happening as it had been working fine for quite some time so I obviously changed something.

forms.py

```
#this is the form for the dropdown
class ManifestDropDown(forms.Form):
    References = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Orders.objects.values_list('reference', flat=True).distinct(),
    empty_label=None)
```

manifest_references.html

```
<!--html for dropdown-->

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">

  <form method="POST" action="manifest">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ reference_list }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Submit</button>
  </form>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
#view for dropdown
def manifest_references(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            reference_id = form.cleaned_data.get('References')
            form.save()

    query_results = Orders.objects.all()
    reference_list = ManifestDropDown()

    context = {
        'query_results': query_results,
        'reference_list': reference_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'manifest_references.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^manifest_references', manifest_references, name='manifest_references'),
```

base.html

```
<!--showing the link to this url-->
...

<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'manifest_references' %}">Edit Manifests</a>
```

When I access the url above - instead of showing the `manifest_references` view with the dropdown, it immediately jumps to a different view `manifest` which is referenced as the `action` in the `manifest_references.html`. Please someone help me determine why this is happening.

Comment: I guess your other URL is mapped to `r'^manifest'`? That would also match `manifest_references`.

Comment: You should show the whole urls.py.

Comment: @KlausD. I feel like an idiot - but yes good guess and thank you for that

Comment: unrelated but note also your `manifest_references` view is using an undeclared variable `form`.

Comment: @dirkgroten hmm could you explain that further for me? Not exactly sure the change I should make

Comment: ‘if form.is_valid():` what is `form`?